Van Kampen's Theorem and simplicial complexes
Suppose we have a simplicial complex $K$, and denote by $|K|$ its geometric realisation.
Is there a compact way of describing the fundamental group of $|K|$ using only the connectivity relations of $K$ (by viewing $K$ as a hypergraph)?
I imagine something along the lines of the generators being cycles in the $1$-skeleton of $K$, with some relations arising from the higher dimensional faces.

Consider reading Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology" book.

Assume $K$ connected, otherwise pass to a connected component. Then the $1$-skeleton $G$ is connected, so pick a spanning tree $T$. Then $G \simeq G/T$ is a wedge of circles indexed by edges of $G$ not in $T$, so has $\pi_1$ a free group, with the generators again indexed by edges of $G$ not in $T$. By repeated applications of Seifert-van Kampen (and passing to the colimit if $K$ has infinitely many simplices), $\pi_1(|K|)$ is a quotient of $\pi_1(G/T)$ by relations given by the boundary of each $2$-simplex: fix an orientation of each edge not in $T$, traverse the boundary in some orientation and record the edges not in $T$ as a word in $F$. This gives a presentation in terms of the edges and the $2$-edges in the hypergraph $K$.
